# Elastic Search version conflict issue

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am using an elastic search for search purpose. But recently I observer that some random error while adding data into elastic search:

> version conflict, required seqNo [113789], primary term [19]. current document has seqNo [113797] and primary term [19]

The above type error comes randomly and I am not able to add/update data in elastic search.
Can you please help to understand:

1. What is the root cause of this issue?
2. How I can reproduce this issue? as this coming randomly need to know the basic step to reproduce this issue
3. What is the solution for this? How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This error happened during an update of the document at the same time others updated it. Check the parallelism.

When this process read the document it had the version number 113789 and when ES received the update did not match with the version number (current version 113797). It causes the version conflict.

Comment: and how can be solved?